# Pivot each group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Using Pandas I've invoked groupby on my dataframe and obtained the following:

```
>>>grouped = df.groupby(['cid'])
for key, gr in grouped:
        print(key)
        print(gr)
Out: cid  price
     121  12
     121  10
     121  9
```

I want to have each group pivoted  like:

```
cid price1 price2 price3
121     12     10      9
```

What is the correct way to do this with Pandas?

Comment: Are you after one large DataFrame of `cid` with columns of `price1`-`priceN` or just the prices per each group?

Comment: The original dataframe has two columns: cids and prices

Comment: I get that part. Do you want the prices per group, or per the whole frame? eg... if the longest group has 1000 prices, do you want a dataframe of 1000 columns with NaNs for the `cid`s that only had 5/6/whatever prices, or are you just wanting it on a group by group basis...

Comment: well, I've  checked: fortunately I got fixed number of prices per cid. So per group or per frame doesn't matter.

Comment: It's good to have small sample datasets but this is actually too small.  Would be good to have at least 2 different values for 'cid'.  Regardless, you'll likely want to use either `stack()` or `pivot()`.  It would be nice to see what you have already tried, if anything.

Comment: Agreeing with and extending JohnE's comment above - you need to show raw output for what is in `df` for us to help you here.  I can't see exactly how that `Out` can come from the code you post - it should print the value of `key` (i.e. 121) first.  Make a dataframe with two `cid` values, show the output of `print(df)` for that and show exactly what output you want for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a frame looking like

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"cid": np.arange(64)//8, "price": np.arange(64)})
>>> df.head()
   cid  price
0    0      0
1    0      1
2    0      2
3    0      3
4    0      4
```

Then I think you can get what you want by combining `groupby` and `pivot`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"cid": np.arange(64)//8, "price": np.arange(64)})
df["num"] = df.groupby("cid")["price"].cumcount() + 1
pivoted = df.pivot(index="cid", columns="num", values="price")
pivoted.columns = "price" + pivoted.columns.astype(str)
pivoted = pivoted.reset_index()
```

which gives

```
>>> pivoted
   cid  price1  price2  price3  price4  price5  price6  price7  price8
0    0       0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
1    1       8       9      10      11      12      13      14      15
2    2      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23
3    3      24      25      26      27      28      29      30      31
4    4      32      33      34      35      36      37      38      39
5    5      40      41      42      43      44      45      46      47
6    6      48      49      50      51      52      53      54      55
7    7      56      57      58      59      60      61      62      63
```

Aside: sticking numbers after the end of strings, e.g. "price5", is usually not a good idea.  You can't really work with them, they don't sort the way you'd expect, etc.

---

First, we create a column showing what index something is in the price:

```
>>> df["num"] = df.groupby("cid")["price"].cumcount() + 1
>>> df.head(10)
   cid  price  num
0    0      0    1
1    0      1    2
2    0      2    3
[etc.]
7    0      7    8
8    1      8    1
9    1      9    2
```

Then we `pivot`:

```
>>> pivoted = df.pivot(index="cid", columns="num", values="price")
>>> pivoted
num   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
cid                                
0     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1     8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
2    16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
3    24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
4    32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
5    40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
6    48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
7    56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
```

Then we fix the columns:

```
>>> pivoted.columns = "price" + pivoted.columns.astype(str)
>>> pivoted
     price1  price2  price3  price4  price5  price6  price7  price8
cid                                                                
0         0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
1         8       9      10      11      12      13      14      15
2        16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23
3        24      25      26      27      28      29      30      31
4        32      33      34      35      36      37      38      39
5        40      41      42      43      44      45      46      47
6        48      49      50      51      52      53      54      55
7        56      57      58      59      60      61      62      63
```

And finally we reset the index:

```
>>> pivoted = pivoted.reset_index()
>>> pivoted
   cid  price1  price2  price3  price4  price5  price6  price7  price8
0    0       0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
1    1       8       9      10      11      12      13      14      15
2    2      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23
3    3      24      25      26      27      28      29      30      31
4    4      32      33      34      35      36      37      38      39
5    5      40      41      42      43      44      45      46      47
6    6      48      49      50      51      52      53      54      55
7    7      56      57      58      59      60      61      62      63
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick variation on @DSM's approach, using `unstack()`.  I'll borrow @DSM's sample data, to keep it easy to compare results from `pivot()` vs `unstack()`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"cid": np.arange(64)//8, "price": np.arange(64)})
>>> df['num'] = df.groupby('cid').cumcount()
>>> df.set_index(['cid','num']).unstack()

    price                            
num     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
cid                                  
0       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1       8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
2      16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
3      24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
4      32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
5      40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
6      48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
7      56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
```